# QMediaPlayer doesn't produce audio

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I am starting out in C++ and I am trying to play an mp3 file with Qt. I wrote this code but it is not working for some reason. I have searched the internet but was unable to find something that would help.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QUrl>

int main()
{
    QMediaPlaylist *list = new QMediaPlaylist;
    list->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("Filename.mp3").absoluteFilePath()));
    QMediaPlayer *music;
    music = new QMediaPlayer();
    music->setPlaylist(list);
    music->play();
    return 0;
}
```

There is no music playing and the output of this program is:

> QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
>   QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Here's my `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MediaPlayer
QT += core multimedia
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**Environment**:

> Fedora 29
>   Qt 5.11.3-1

I tried to run this program on Qt creator and on terminal.

Comment: Use: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMediaPlaylist *list = new QMediaPlaylist;
    list->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("Filename.mp3").absoluteFilePath()));
    QMediaPlayer *music;
    music = new QMediaPlayer();
    music->setPlaylist(list);
    music->play();
    return app.exec();
}`

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is missing a

- `QCoreApplication` if it is supposed to be headless
- `QGuiApplication` for QtQuick, or
- `QApplication` if it features Widgets

`Q*Application` is a mandatory component for most Qt applications, as this is the piece that processes all events and signal on the main thread. This is the reason why you are having `QTimer` related errors, as Qt was not able to "wrap" the main thread with a `QThread` beforehand.

Just add it, as well as `app.exec();` to start it, and you should be fine. `app.exec()` will block until your application finishes.

Also, instances that you need during the whole lifetime of the application should usually be created on the stack, instead of the heap.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlaylist list;
    auto media = QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("Filename.mp3").absoluteFilePath());
    list.addMedia(media);

    QMediaPlayer music;
    music.setPlaylist(list);
    music.play();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What craziness is it to be REQUIRED to create objects ones to be used during whole lifetime on the stack? We actually noticed this not to work on heap in some cases. Why craziness? For one, the object can't be accessed through multiple clients.